# Meaning of 你怎麼好到我這裡來!

Tags: word, sentence

你怎麼**好**到我這裡來!

What does this sentence mean in general, and specifically what does **好** mean here?

More context:

李先生站起來，走到帳幕門口去一看，黃弟弟正蹲在那裡! "你怎麼**好**到我這裡來!" 李先生急得滿頭大汗!

Comment: please provide more context

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Such a construct is not generally used. Possibly at some locations...

Comment: What's the relationship and what happened between 李先生 and 黄弟弟? More context will be helpful. One possible meaning is that you can replace `好(hao4)` to `经常` or `喜欢`, something like 'Why you often/like come to my place' with a different context: 黄 is not harmful to 李, but a little bit annoying, so the mood of 李 is between peace and angry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, "好" means  "appropriate"

"你怎麼好到我這裡" = "How is it appropriate for you to come to my place?" (imply it is inappropriate)

It is possible that 黃弟弟 going to 李先生's  place might cause trouble for either or both of them

It sounds like a regional usage of 好. Typical Mandarin would say "你到我這裡怎麼合適?"

Answer (score 0):

Here, 好 = 能夠/可以/敢

- 你怎麼好... = How could/dare you.....

Comment: Seriously? I thought 好 just meant good/positive.

Comment: 好 carries a hidden message - "**為了你好**, 你不應該到我這裡來!".

Answer (score 0):

你怎麼好到我這裡? = 你怎么可以到我这里来?

In plain Anglosaxon 李 said: What the f*** are you doing here?